# How can I repartition RDD by key and then pack it to shards?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pytorch

I have many files containing millions of rows in format:

```
id, created_date, some_value_a, some_value_b, some_value_c
```

This way of repartitioning was super slow and created for me over million of small ~500b files:

```
    rdd_df = rdd.toDF(["id", "created_time", "a", "b", "c"])
    rdd_df.write.partitionBy("id").csv("output")
```

I would like to achieve output files, where each file contains like 10000 unique IDs and all their rows.

How could I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can repartition by adding a Random Salt key.

```
val totRows = rdd_df.count

val maxRowsForAnId = rdd_df.groupBy("id").count().agg(max("count"))
val numParts1 = totRows/maxRowsForAnId


val totalUniqueIds = rdd_df.select("id").distinct.count
val numParts2 = totRows/(10000*totalUniqueIds)

val numPart = numParts1.min(numParts2)


rdd_df
 .repartition(numPart,col("id"),rand)
 .csv("output")
```

The main concept is `each partition will be written as 1 file`. SO you would have  bring your required rows in to 1 partition by `repartition(numPart,col("id"),rand)`.

The first 4-5 operations is just to calculate how many partitions we need to achieve almost 10000 ids per file.

- Calculate assuming 10000 ids per partition
- Corner case : if a single `id` has too many rows and doesn't fit in the above calculated partition size.
- Hence we calculate no of paritition according to the largest count of ID present
- Take min of the 2 noOfPartitons

`rand` is necessary so, that we can bring multiple IDs in a single partition

**NOTE :** Although this will give you larger files and each file will contain a set of unique ids for sure. But this involves `shuffling` , due to which your operation actually might be slower than the code you have mentioned in question.

Answer (score -1):

You would need something like this:

```
rdd_df.repartition(*number of partitions you want*).write.csv("output", header = True)
```

or honestly - just let the job decide the number partitions instead of repartitioning. In theory, that should be faster:

```
rdd_df.write.csv("output", header = True)
```

Comment: There are other ways as well-
1. Write it as a table and then use zorder by to optimize the table before rewriting them.

Comment: But with both ways you've provided me I doesn't include grouping by key. I want group of ids to be unique for single partition.